# QWebview и QScrollBar который устанавливается не до конца

Tags: qt, qt5, qtcreator, qt4

Здравствуйте суть проблемы в том что вертикальный scrollbar не устанавливается до конца., когда я добавляю текст в QWebView
Суть на скриншоте.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
И так теперь код:

```
 //Просто добавляет строку текста в QWebView
    void MainWindow::WriteToWebView(QString szSrc)
    {
           QWebElement elDoc = ui->webView->page()->mainFrame()->documentElement();

           if(!elDoc.isNull())
           {
               QWebElement elBody = elDoc.findFirst("body");

               if(!elBody.isNull())
               {
                    elBody.appendInside(szSrc + "<br /> ");
               }

           }
           //Тут пытаюсь установить на максимум вертикальный scrollbar
           ui->webView->page()->mainFrame()->setScrollBarValue(Qt::Vertical, ui->webView->page()->mainFrame()->scrollBarMaximum(Qt::Vertical));
    }
```

Так вот как заставить вертикальный scrollbar опускаться до конца, ибо после добавления, остается место.

Answer (score 1):

Корень всех проблем `QWebElement` который добавляет текст, соб-но используйте метод `setHtml` или `setContent`.